# How to validate cascade delete when no corresponding table entry exists for that entry?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have these 2 models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, related_name="categories")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and

```
class Item(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, related_name="items")
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="items")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    isPartiallySellable = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=500,default="")
```

when I am deleting a category entry, I am getting the following error on django

```
column item.isPartiallySellable does not exist
LINE 1: ...currentlyInStock", "item"."unit", "...
                                             ^
```

Now, I don't have any entry in Item table, but still getting this error. I want the cascading to happen but I am not able to debug this particular error. On a side note this error has a partial one, how can I get the full error message here.

Comment: Did u added isPartiallySellable after migrating? If yes, did u run makemigrations and migrate?

Answer (score 2):

This is a real issue with your database where constraints aren't guaranteed. You should run a sanity check to ensure all the foreign keys are up to date.

Note: if you can't fix the database itself, you'll have to override the delete function and ensure the FK do exist by yourself.

Comment: yeah, my migrations were not synced. Faked them and deleted objects again. worked like a charm.